# Encoder Timebase is not set - audio duplication error, FPS problem

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, audio, frame-rate

I understand this question has been asked but I cannot find a solution to my particular problem.

When I try to animate my video project I get the error 'The Encoder Timebase is not set' - through this forum I found out that when I imported my video Blender changed it from 60fps down to 59.96fps.

Before animating I changed the fps back to 60 which allowed the animation process to begin. When my video had rendered I found that the audio tracks seem to have multiplied and overlayed each other. I also found that my Movie sequencer had lots of extra audio in it. In addition to this I found my outputted video had severely dropped in quality from the original 1080p.

Please see here for examples of what I am referring to -
[image: Before FPS Change]

[image: After FPS Change]

[image: Example output quality]

Thank you so much for any help, total beginner here having a meltdown!

Paul

Answer (score -1):

As suggested elsewhere I managed to export the audio as a .wav and then remove the audio track, set to 60fps and then overlay exported .wav file. I’m just animating at a higher quality than last time so I will know if this worked soon :)